# If $a$ is an infinite cardinal and $a \leq bc$, prove that $ a \leq b$ or $a \leq c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $a$ is an infinite cardinal and $a \leq bc$, prove that $ a \leq b$ or $a \leq c$ is the statement i am trying to prove.

My attempt

Suppose $a \leq bc$.
Then since $a$ is an infinite cardinal $bc$ must be an infinite cardinal and since $bc=max\{b,c\}$, we have $ a \leq b$ or $a \leq c$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: Your proof works.